# Is this a referentially transparent function?

Tags: functional-programming

Is the following `add()` function referentially transparent?

```
const appState = {
    runningTotal: 0
}

function add(x, y) {
    const total = x + y;
    appState.runningTotal += total;
    return total;
}
```

I'm unsure of the answer due to a handful of definitions I've found for referential transparency. Here are some in the order of my confidence of their correctness.

A function is referentially transparent if:

1. It can be replaced by its value and the behavior of the program remains the same
2. Given some input it will always produce the same output
3. It only depends on its input
4. It is stateless

Given each of the definitions above I would think the answer is:

1. Maybe - I think it depends on how appState.runningTotal is used elsewhere in the program, but I'm not sure.
2. Yes
3. I'm not sure - It only depends on its input *to produce the output*, but it also uses `appState` in the body of the function
4. No

Back to the specific question: is `add()` referentially transparent?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. - please let me know if I'm conflating multiple concepts, namely the concept of a `pure function`.

Comment: But if you replace each `add` call with its return value, it would always be `0`, because `runningTotal` would never be mutated. `add`'s result doesn't depend on the input at all.

Comment: @ftor thanks for replying. I’m not sure I follow. The return value of `add` is unaffected by `runningTotal`. Also `add`’s result is solely dependent on its input (`x` and `y`)

Comment: Yes, it depends on the input, my mistake. However, if you substitute `add` with its return value, `runningTotal` is never incremented. This is a change in behavior. Bergi points out that this isn't harmful, as long as other parts of the program doesn't depend on `runningTotal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't a referentially transparent function.

Referential transparency refers specifically to the first criteria you have listed, namely that you can freely substitute the values on the left and right hand side of an expression without changing the behaviour of the program.

`add(2,3)` returns the value `5` but you cannot replace instances of `add(2,3)` with `5` in your program because `add(2, 3)` also has the *side effect* of incrementing `runningTotal` by `5`.  Substituting `add(2, 3)` for `5` would result in `runningTotal` not being incremented, changing the behaviour of your program.

Comment: Is definition 2 - `Given some input it will always produce the same output` - then incorrect? Or at least incomplete? This seems to be the most prevalent definition, and from my understanding directly influences the answer.    Thanks for the answer by the way! :-)

Comment: Also what do you think about @Bergi’s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49350185/1072030)? I’m going to ask him the same thing of yours since they differ. Thanks again!

Comment: @ChaseMiller People often talk about giving the same input for the same output but it is indeed an incomplete definition.  The key point about referential transparency is the ability to perform value substitution and hence the absence of side effects.  It does logically follow though that if a function is referentially transparent, it must return the same output for the same input.

Comment: that helps to clarify things. A few people have said that `add` is transparent if `appState.runningTotal` is not used elsewhere in the program. Would you agree? Thanks again.

Comment: @ChaseMiller The question feels quite philosophical at this point.  It depends on what things you choose to include in your definition of program behaviour.  It probably results in different code being executed although, if it's never used, that might get optimised away by a clever compiler.  I would probably still consider it not referentially transparent as the side effect still exists *in your own code*.  I would place side effects created by the compiler in a different category as they don't exist in the code itself and (hopefully) behave in a predictable way.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with

> Maybe - It depends on how `appState.runningTotal` is used

as when it is not used, then it can be ignored. Obviously it is global state, but is it just for debugging or is it part of your actual application state? If the latter, then the function is not pure of course - it does change the state and replacing a call with the result value (or doing unnecessary calls whose result is dropped) would change the behaviour of your program.

But if you do consider `appState.runningTotal` to not be part of the semantics of your program, and non of its functionality depends on it, you might as well ignore this side effect. We do this all the time, every real world computation affects the state of the computer it runs on, and we choose to ignore that when we consider the purity of our functions.

Comment: Totally agree, RT is a desirable property but you can break it if it is local or you know what you're doing. However, this doesn't apply if the compiler/interpreter depends on RT, in order to conduct further optimizations.

Comment: @ftor In that case, the compiler/interpreter will need to follow the spec in what it needs to consider a side effect, which might be a different model for RT than the programmer wants to consider. With regards to the EcmaScript, an assignment like `appState.runningTotal += total;` of course must not be ignored and the function is impure.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying! What do you think about @TheInnerLight’s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49342875/1072030)? I asked him the same thing of yours since they differ. Thanks again!

Comment: @ChaseMiller He's correct. Your function has a "*side effect of incrementing, and substituting would change the behaviour of your program.*" I'm just being more specific: if incrementing (or not) `runningTotal` does not change the behaviour of your program, then you still can consider it pure.

Comment: @ChaseMiller Similarly, `2 + 3` would probably be considered a pure operation. But by replacing it with `5`, the program does now execute differently - it might run faster, a tracer would count one less addition. Whether we consider that difference to be a change in the program's behaviour only we can decide.

Answer (score 0):

A pure function is referentially transparent. I call it "copypastability", aka you can copy paste each part of referentially transparent code around, and it'll still work as originally intended.

All of the four criteria have to be fulfilled, although you can shrink them to the first statement. The others can all be inferred from that one.

If a function can be reasonably replaced, that means you can replace it with a map/dictionary which has input as keys and outputs as values. So it'll always return the same thing on the same input. The same analogy works just fine with the "only depends on input" and "stateless".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So does that mean that the function referentially transparent? :-)  Based on what you said I think the answer would be “no”.